# TypeScript how to use typeof with generic prototype?

Tags: typescript

How can I write  `typeof PoolConnection<TDefaultValue>.prototype[K]` ?

That doesn't seem to be valid syntax, and I'm losing type information because of it. Here's a fuller example:

```
export type DefaultValueType = string | number | boolean | Date | bigint | null

type NotImportant = any
export const META = 'meta'
export type QueryResult<T> = T[] & { [META]: NotImportant[] }

class ConnectionPool<TDefaultValue = DefaultValueType> {

    constructor(private readonly pool: NotImportant) {
    }

    async getConnection() {
        return new PoolConnection<TDefaultValue>(await this.pool.getConnection())
    }

    // PROBLEM IS HERE: losing type information in the return value
    private _fwd<K extends keyof typeof PoolConnection.prototype>(method: K): typeof PoolConnection.prototype[K] {
        return (async (...args: any[]) => {
            const conn = await this.getConnection()
            try {
                return await (conn[method] as any)(...args)
            } finally {
                // release connection
            }
        }) as any
    }

    query = this._fwd('query')
}

class PoolConnection<TDefaultValue = DefaultValueType> {
    
    constructor(private readonly conn: NotImportant) {
    }

    query<TRecord = Record<string, TDefaultValue>>(query: NotImportant): Promise<QueryResult<TRecord>> {
        return Promise.resolve([] as any)
    }
}


async function test() {
    const pool = new ConnectionPool<string>('secret')

    // `result` should be QueryResult<Record<string, string>> but is QueryResult<Record<string, any>>
    const result = await pool.query("select * from users")  

    const conn2 = new PoolConnection<boolean>('secret')
    // type is correct: QueryResult<Record<string, boolean>>
    const result2 = await conn2.query("select * from profiles");

     const conn3 = new PoolConnection('secret')
    // type is correct: QueryResult<Record<string, DefaultValueType>>
    const result3 = await conn3.query("select * from profiles");
}
```

What's even weirder, is that it's coming out `QueryResult<Record<string, any>>` instead of falling back to `QueryResult<Record<string, DefaultValueType>>`

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiwBmBDArgGxgDVt9dgAVZVAXjgGcYoBLAOwHM4AfOV3AWwBGwKNziCIEfMGysxabDFQ9Bzdm3g8++fAChdSFHAByEGAEl+kWLPh1ZiXaGvwAxhFaM4AWQCiFAEE4OgByfmAYbBCncGh4Q1QARXIoRAAlYHoCGAAeCgA+YLgKAG0AXTgAMjgAbzgSv0CygC4TM0sXW3K4AF99V3xseno4AGEPVmBXGGYPAAVJfDyMHGySMlp0LDxCdfIqFEKa-ThTuHdPJlxp6AAKMBYAN0VUKBkAEw98RDhIKVbTBYrHFbABKWq6M69E5nIaIViuODsCLjViTaazVi3cHHKFQt4wXBQOSTADucAWUlR6JmHmW2zWpHI+Vu2FJ2GY8QAFsx6AA6P74PnImDUqa0rGg0GQs59GWnAD0CopaQA8gAhAAyvm8cHMAGU4AAJXxpXytfAQehsTgJOBsTDQfiKTH2uQwLmvCJEuTPDby35PF5wAD6mFJ7xyAGk4KAlKx3iMANbARAQTAIajpimLMUYjwCqBmMzUFnhD0Qd6tKOg1oJbOU-B5iWF4sJEpRiq4vGnAk+uCs+jwxG3Plj7BQdj0VoOcrgmhHAM904XLwXOT2dmchA8-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-kF2XLJQUwNDm53hDaKQ49REvW94pfT9ED8IG6bMNIQOggA3L1XNrhMADMMNw7mCMSlRmPYwGMH4yMhPiiTe3kwdoWLWtNNbKsdkCaWjNQuD10wMrHPbuuiu87R-PAO98DfZgv0POLkvA7LPRAA)

---

If it helps understand what's going on here, `ConnectionPool` is a pool of database connections. `PoolConnection` is a single connection in the pool.

`ConnectionPool` mostly just gets available connections and forwards them to the individual connection. That's what `_fwd` is supposed to do. I want it to pull all the type information from the `PoolConnection` because I have a dozen of these methods that I'm forwarding and I don't want to reimplement each of them twice.

Comment: Pls share reproducable example. PoolConnection expects 0 arguments and you have provided 1. It will be easier to help if you leave only errors you have problem with\

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry, shouldn't have pruned the c'tor. I fixed up the example and the link

Answer (score 0):

you can use InstenceOf for example

```
const pool = new ConnectionPool<string>('secret')

if( pool Instanceof ConnectionPool<string>)
// expected output: true
```

Here you can read more on that

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. The TypeScript return type on `pool.query` is incorrect. Runtime/JS is fine.